# Firestore index limitation

Tags: firebase, indexing, google-cloud-firestore, database-indexes

From the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#indexes) Firestore has, among others, these limitations:

- Maximum number of index entries for each document: **40,000**
- Maximum sum of the sizes of a document's index entries: **8 MiB**

I'm having some difficulty understanding what the docs mean by a "document" here. Do they refer to one single document, or the whole set of documents of a specific collection?

For example, suppose I have a collection which contains 10,000 documents, and each document contains the same 2 fields:

```
Document: `students/00001`
  name: "Jeff"
  age: 32

Document: `students/00002`
  name: "Mary"
  age: 28

...

Document: `students/10000`
  name: "Anne"
  age: 45
```

According to the docs, Firestore will create one index for each field in ascending order, and one more index for each field in descending order. Thus, we'll have 4 indexes for each document, and only these same 4 indexes for the entire collection of documents, since they all have the same fields.

All is well.

However, now suppose I have a collection which also contains 10,000 documents, but where each document contains **2 fields which are always different from each other**:

```
Document: `students/00001`
  B2DcG6g9w: true
  YwY3g642D: true

Document: `students/00002`
  A3h7k3e6B: true
  w2Fh0j1g8: true

...

Document: `students/10000`
  8n4545f7k: true
  j2hle4oOp: true
```

Firestore will create one index for each field in ascending order, and one more index for each field in descending order. Thus, we'll have **only 4 indexes for each document**. But since these indexes are different for each document we will have a **total of 40,000 indexes for all the documents in the collection**.

**Question:** Have I reached the 40,000 index limit, or not? Is that limitation really by document or is it by collection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a single index created for each field or combination of fields that you index in a collection. Each document can be present in 40.000 of such indexes.

Comment: "Each document can be present in 40.000 of such indexes." In other words, it's a total of 40,000 indexes for each document, and NOT for collection. So, in my example above I have NOT reached any limits.

Comment: Would you say this answer of yours also answers this question?: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54369877/firestore-chat-app-is-this-a-valid-document-structure-for-multi-recipient-messa

Comment: "So, in my example above I have NOT reached any limits." that is correct.

Answer (score 2):

The number of documents in the collection is irrelevant to the stated limits.  Documents that lack a field won't have an index for that field.  (Firestore won't index on something that doesn't exist.) You are able to [remove indexes](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing#remove_indexes) in order to save space and money.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I know the number of documents is irrelevant. My question is really if the index limit is per document or per collection.

Comment: When you said "But since these indexes are different for each document we will have a total of 40,000 indexes for all the documents in the collection" it sounded like you were suggesting that adding more documents in a collection would cause problems. That's why I'm saying that the number of documents in a collection is irrelevant. You aren't effectively force-creating indexes for every other document simply by adding a new document with a unique field.  The limits are per document. You will have a problem if you try to create many combinations of indexes against many fields in a document.

Comment: Yes, but I was insecure about it because, as I understand it, indexes are not per document, but per collection. If two documents in a collection have the same field, they will be indexed by a single collection index, not 2 indexes (one for each document, which would not make sense). Indexes are in the collection level, so I was afraid the limitation was 40,000 indexes per collection. If the limitation is 40,000 indexes per document, then I can implement this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54369877/firestore-chat-app-is-this-a-valid-document-structure-for-multi-recipient-messa